# JQ for creating a table from a Json File

Tags: json, bash, jq

Just started out with Bash scripting and stumbled upon jq to work with JSON.
I tried multiple things via jq, but unable to get proper formatting as the data changes the output readability goes for a toss

I have this at the moment but as the data changes , the table becomes a mess,

```
echo  "$(jq -r '[(.Results[].Vulnerabilities[] | {VulnerabilityID,PkgName,Severity,InstalledVersion,FixedVersion})] | ["VulnerabilityID","PkgName","       Severity","InstalledVersion","FixedVersion"], ["---------------","-------", "       -------", "----------------", "------------"], (.[] | [.VulnerabilityID, .PkgName, .Severity, .InstalledVersion, .FixedVersion]) | @tsv' json.json)" >> output.txt
```

I need to transform a JSON string like below to a table for output in the terminal.
https://dpaste.org/iKG9n

I want to display in the terminal:

```
VulnerabilityID PkgName     Severity    InstalledVersion    FixedVersion
--------------- -------     -------     ----------------    ------------
CVE-2021-33910  libsystemd0 HIGH        237-3ubuntu10.43    237-3ubuntu10.49
CVE-2021-33910  libudev1    HIGH        237-3ubuntu10.43    237-3ubuntu10.49
```

Comment: sorry i have update my json file, if anyone already took a look at it

Comment: Add your JSON file to your question (no link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can use `jq` to inspect all values in a column, then pad each item with spaces (or dashes) to align them having equal widths, but there are external tools already doing exactly that. One of them is `column` from [util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux). Use it like this:

```bash
jq -r '… | @tsv' json.json | column -t  # append >> output.txt if needed
```

```
VulnerabilityID  PkgName      Severity  InstalledVersion  FixedVersion
---------------  -------      -------   ----------------  ------------
CVE-2021-33910   libsystemd0  HIGH      237-3ubuntu10.43  237-3ubuntu10.49
CVE-2021-33910   libudev1     HIGH      237-3ubuntu10.43  237-3ubuntu10.49
```

Comment: perfect!  gracious